# in angular.js what is the difference between using $scope(the older version) and vm(the newer version)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are barely any sights out there or tutorials walking through the use of vm or View model.  Any ideas?  How does eliminating the use of $scope effect ones code in html using angular?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

See [Johnpapa's blog](https://johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/). That will help you

Comment: if you going to link to some code, you should include some of it in the answer. in an event the URL is no longer valid.